# Highcharts-ng charts[i].getSVGForLocalExport is not a function

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, pdf-generation

I'm trying to export multiple charts as a single pdf, client side, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/eatqca8n/ but I'm getting an error that getSVGForLocalExport is not a function. Is this an issue with highcharts-ng?

```
/**
 * Create a global getSVG method that takes an array of charts as an argument. The SVG is returned as an argument in the callback.
 */
Highcharts.getSVG = function(charts, options, callback) {
    var svgArr = [],
            top = 0,
        width = 0,
        i,
        svgResult = function (svgres) {
            var svg = svgres.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
            svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');
            top += charts[i].chartHeight;
            width = Math.max(width, charts[i].chartWidth);
            svgArr.push(svg);
            if (svgArr.length === charts.length) {
              callback('<svg height="'+ top +'" width="' + width + '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>');
            }
        };
        for (i = 0; i < charts.length; ++i) {
                charts[i].getSVGForLocalExport(options, {}, function () { 
            console.log("Failed to get SVG");
        }, svgResult);
        }
};

/**
 * Create a global exportCharts method that takes an array of charts as an argument,
 * and exporting options as the second argument
 */
Highcharts.exportCharts = function(charts, options) {
        // Merge the options
    options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, options);    

    var imageType = options && options.type || 'image/png';

        // Get SVG asynchronously and then download the resulting SVG
    Highcharts.getSVG(charts, options, function (svg) {
      Highcharts.downloadSVGLocal(svg,
        (options.filename || 'chart')  + '.' + (imageType === 'image/svg+xml' ? 'svg' : imageType.split('/')[1]),
        imageType,
        options.scale || 2,
        function () {
          console.log("Failed to export on client side");
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: I am not seeing any method called getSVGForLocalExportin the highcharts or highcharts-ng documentation.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Yeah, I haven't seen it either.

Comment: It is part of the [offline-exporting module](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export), see [source here](http://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.src.js). Have you included the 2 exporting modules like in the example you linked to? i.e. `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>`